# How can find a record based on array object key-value in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a record in database:

```
{
  "name" : "user",
  "number":"09xxxxxxx21",
  "pc" : [{
      "pcId" : "1",
      "pcName" : "Desktop",
      "pcOwner" : "user1"
    }, {
      "pcId" : "2",
      "pcName" : "Laptop",
      "pcOwner" : "user1"
    }
  ]}
}
```

Using mongo find query I'm able to get record when giving name but I want to fetch record based on pcId.

Comment: See [Query an Array of Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.find({"pc.pcId": "2"})
```

As pcId is the child element of `pc` you need to refer to the parent first to reach that element.

for reference: https://mongoplayground.net/p/uWD9tPPhupR

Answer (score 0):

I think you were looking for something like this.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/LsUCVSj_7_e

```
db.collection.find({
  "pc.pcId": "12"
})
```

This works perfect.